# how to fill two textbox via one datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I have two Texbox with datetime type, I want to fill both of them with one Datetimepicker. I mean first textbox is start date and second textbox is end date for project, default period for each project is 30 days. when I select 3/24/2015 via datetime picker first textbox should be 3/24/2015 and second text box automatically should be 4/24/2015 . how can I do this?

this is my code :

```
<input type="text" onclick="displayDatePicker('start', this, 'ymd')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$(function() {
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en']);
  $('#startdate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      $('#endDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date); // Reset minimum date
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30); // Add 7 days
      $("#enddate").datepicker("setDate", date); // Set as default
    }
  });
  $('#enddate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      $('#startdate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate')); // Reset maximum date
    }
  });
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
    $(function() {
          $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en']);
          $('#startdate').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                $('#endDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date); // Reset minimum date
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30); // Add 7 days
                $("#enddate").datepicker( "setDate",  date); // Set as default
          }});
          $('#enddate').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                $('#startdate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate')); // Reset maximum date
          }});
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" id="startdate" />
<input type="text" id="enddate" />
```